# Drupal fatal error allowed memory size, can't update limit

Tags: php, drupal, memory, configuration, drupal-7

I know this question has been posted here, but I can't seem to fix it.

The problem is that Drupal needed more memory than php was allowed to give it.

running a phpinfo() I find the configuration file path is: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini 
and I adjusted that file. (memory_limit = 1028)

I also adjusted: 
main php.ini (MAMP/conf/php5.4.10)
drupal settings.php (MAMP/htdocs/drupal-7.24/sites/default/settings.php)

nothing seems to work.. 
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you update it in a .htaccess file?

```
php_value memory_limit 1028M
```

Or is this not an option?

Comment: whats that filepath? or where should i create it? (it's possible as i'm only working local)

Comment: Look at this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/where-is-htaccess-located-in-drupal-7

Comment: found the file, but there's no such line. I added the line, but didnt help

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the configure file is not the right one. You should run `phpinfo()` in the php script which is access by the webserver.

You can try to set it in your php script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

Comment: where is that php script set? i'm adjusting it in the conf dir of MAMP installation, should be the file accessed by webserver?

Comment: I saw there is a config php file `MAMP/htdocs/drupal-7.24/sites/default/settings.php`, write the config code here, if it is the config file.

Comment: Or write a php file: `phpinfo.php` with just one line: `<php? phpinfo();?>` to you webserver root. Then visit the via the browser, find out the real php.ini file location.

Comment: Have you restart your webserver?